# Panasonic SDR-H100 Multiple Program Files

Tags: video, camcorder

I have a Panasonic SDR-H100 camcorder. When I shoot videos, with stoppages, i.e. many clips, the videos are put into two different program folders within the sd_card folder on my SCHD. I was wondering if there was a way to ensure that those video files are put into the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

If the camera is following DCIM standards, then there should be a 4 digit ID number appended to the end of a 4 digit prefix to form the filename.  The standard is that when a folder is filled (the counter reaches 9999), a new folder is created and the counter starts over again at 1.

While there does not appear to be a way to combine these folders on the camera itself, it should be possible for you to simply copy the files in to the same folder on your PC as long as the names don't overlap.